# KeyError in Python for dictionary

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have excel with worksheets. On worksheet[6], I am searching for some specific strings and getting row number and columns values for that row. Then I am searching for worksheet[0] for specific strings and write the corresponding values to column 5 of worksheet[0].
For example I am searching for 'UC Care' 'PP Visit' in worksheet[6] get columns values and write UC Care column value to `UCR***1` row column 5 of worksheet[0]

Below is my code and I am getting error:

> if coinds_dict[test_name] is not none: KeyError: UCR***1

What is wrong in my code?

```
import numpy as np
import openpyxl as xl

book = xl.load_workbook('Mapping.xlsx')
# Get the values of the first column in the  worksheet[6]
cgs_values = np.array([[cell.value for cell in row] for row in
                   book.worksheets[6].iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=300, min_col=3, 
max_col=3)])

# Create a dictionary to store the row numbers for each test in the workbook[0]
test_rows = {'UCR***1': None, 'POV***1': None, 'SOV***1': None}


# Create a dictionary to store the percentage for each test
coins_dict = {'UC Care': None, 'PP Visit': None, 'SP Visit': None}

# Iterate through the test names
 for test_name in ['UC Care', 'PP Visit', 'SP Visit']:

 # Find the row in the worksheet[6] that contains the text
    row_number = np.where(cgs_values == test_name)[0][0] + 2

# Get the value of the cell in the sixth column of that row
coins = book.worksheets[6].cell(row=row_number, column=6).value

# If the value of the cell is not empty, then calculate the  percentage
if coins is not None:
    # If the value of the cell in the seventh column is "Coins", then calculate the coins percentage and store it in the dictionary
    if book.worksheets[6].cell(row=row_number, column=7).value == "Coins":
        coins = book.worksheets[6].cell(row=row_number, column=6).value
        m1 = 100 - int(coins)
        coins_dict[test_name] = str(m1) + "%" + " " + "Coinsurance"
    # If the value of the cell in the seventh column is "Cody", then calculate the  percentage and store it in the dictionary
    elif book.worksheets[6].cell(row=row_number, column=7).value == "Cody":
        coins = book.worksheets[6].cell(row=row_number, column=6).value
        m1 = 100 - int(coins)
        coins_dict[test_name] = str(m1) + "%" + " " + "after deductible"
   

# Find the row numbers for each test in the  workbook[0]
 for test_name, row_name in test_rows.items():
   for row in book.worksheets[0].iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=book.worksheets[0].max_row, 
   min_col=1, max_col=1):
   if row[0].value == test_name:
        test_rows[test_name] = row[0].row
        break
   if coins_dict[test_name] is not None:
    book.worksheets[0].cell(row=test_rows[test_name], column=5, value=coins_dict[test_name])




  book.save('Mapping.xlsx')
  book.close()
```

Comment: It's wrong that you are trying to access a key in a dictionary that does not exist without handling that potential failure.

Comment: Why did you expect that `'UCR***1'` exists in `coinds_dict`? What even is `coinds_dict`? That's not part of the code you have shown.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up `[]` and `get`. `[]` causes an error on a bad lookup. `get` returns `None` (by default).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a difference between `coinds_dict[test_name]` having a value of `None` and `test_name` not being a valid key in `coinds_dict` at all.

You could explicitly handle the exception, but I think it's more idiomatic to use the following:

```
if test_name not in coinds_dict:
   ...
```

To include the case where the key is `None`, you could do:

```
if test_name not in coinds_dict and coinds_dict[test_name] is not None:
   ...
```